# Do events fired using event emitter persist order

Tags: javascript, node.js, eventemitter

I have little nooby question about event emitter but it is really important for may program logic.

I am using some external library that fires events I am listening. Lets say it fires 2 events : '**data**' and '**error**'. Lets say that lib will always call **data** before **error**, something like this:

```
emit('data', 'some data');
emit('error', 'some error');
```

**Question is**: can I be 100% sure that data event will always come before error event in my listen methods?:

```
lib.on('data', function(data) {
            // is this always first
});

lib.on('error', function(error) {
            // or maybe this
});
```

Thanks,

Ivan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The EventEmitter `emit` function is a synchronous blocking function. And hence, like any other  blocking function, it is guaranteed to execute in the exact order it is called in.